# Build error when using ANT to build Eclipse3.5 source code

Tags: eclipse, ant, build

I have been trying to build Eclipse3.5 source code to create the corresponding .class files and a single jar file. I have been using ANT to do that. However, I am getting a message `Build Failed .. 1 error ..` in my console window. If I am building `jdtcoresrc` part of eclipse source code, it is building successfully. However including the `plugins` directory or running it separately on `plugins` is giving this error.

The Eclipse3.5 source code has around 6920 java files, so there were some out of memory problems initially. This got fixed by including the attributes : 
`fork="true", memoryinitialsize="1024m",  memorymaximumsize="1024m"` in the  tag of build.xml.

FYI, I have downloaded eclipse-sourceBuild-srcIncluded-3.5.zip file and unzipped it to get the source code for eclipse 3.5.

I am pasting the console output for your reference -

```
   [javac] [total 342125ms]
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
C:\CAG\EclipWorkspace\Eclipse.Build\build.xml:34: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 6 minutes 45 seconds
```

As the error is not explicit, I am not sure whether there are any .jar files and/or dependencies that should be added to complete the build process.

I have not been able to get any help regarding building of eclipse code itself (all tutorials talk about building programs within eclipse). I have successfully built Apache Math source code and another small program, so I believe ANT settings are OK.

Can somebody please help me out? I have been wasting a week on this without much progress.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try running ant with debug flag to investigate more.

Comment: what is the compiler's error output?